# Windows UAP Icon Sizes?

Tags: win-universal-app

I'm doing a major overhaul to my icon generation app, and would like to know the required icon sizes for the Windows Universal App Platform (Windows 10).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/tiles-and-notifications-app-assets#Asset_size_tables) guidelines for tile and icon assets from Microsoft. There are several things you should consider so read the guideline and you´ll get a better understand of how to proceed.